# My 2014 Hyundai Sonata Limited stalled/died when turned right after a stop sign

Tags: hyundai, stall, sonata

The Sonata has automatic transmission.
It happened a few times: when I stopped then turned right, the car suddenly stalled with engine still running. But I was able to continue to drive. It was pretty scary. Then, the last time, the car stopped, engine died at the right turn after a stop sign. I had to restart the engine and it ran again.

I went to a Hyundai dealer. They said a battery connect was loose; when I made the right turns after stop, the battery disconnected, thus caused the stall.

Is that true? Since I don't drive the car daily, and the issue had happened only a few times, I have not experienced the same issue since the battery connects were tightened. Therefore, I can't tell if the loose battery connection was the root cause of the car stall.

Comment: I'm having trouble with your terminology. You said "car suddenly stalled with engine still running".  Do you mean the engine stalled or the car stopped moving or something else.  Please EDIT your question and be detailed and specific.

Comment: That the issue hasn't resurfaced since the battery contacts were tightened would lead me to conclude that the shop's diagnosis and repair was correct and effective.